# Combining kableExtra::cell_spec() output with custom S3 formatting methods

Tags: r, dplyr, kable

I'm trying to add colours for conditional formatting in an HTML table that contains a few custom S3 classes. How could I keep the formatting methods I'm using for my S3 classes and still change the look of cells in the table?

For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(a = c(-1.2345, 0, 1.2345), b = c(-1.2345, 0, 1.2345))

format.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  paste(round(x, 2), "♥")
}

class(df$a) <- c("myclass", class(df$a))
class(df$b) <- c("myclass", class(df$b))
```

In this data frame, all numbers are displayed correctly for this class:

```
> df
        a       b
1 -1.23 ♥ -1.23 ♥
2     0 ♥     0 ♥
3  1.23 ♥  1.23 ♥
```

But it no longer works when I add kableExtra styling properties to a cell:

```r
df %>% mutate(a = cell_spec(a, color = ifelse(a<0, "red", "green"))) %>% 
  kable(., escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Is there a way to keep `myclass` formatting when using `cell_spec()`?

---

**Update:** Calling the class formatter explicitly makes this work:

```r
df %>% mutate(a = cell_spec(format.myclass(a), color = ifelse(a<0, "red", "green"))) %>% 
  kable(., escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

But is there a way to call this formatter automatically for its class?